# how to display pdf in embed tag after click button?

Tags: laravel, embed, dompdf

I have a form with a filter and a submit button. I would like to display a pdf in an embed tag on the same page with the filter fields used when generating the pdf with Dompdf. Thanks in advance.

**here is the form :**

```
@section('content')
<!-- Your html goes here -->
<div class='panel panel-default'>
    <div class='panel-heading'>Customer Statement</div>
    <div class='panel-body'>
    <form method='get' action="{{ route('getStatement') }}" id="statementForm">
            @csrf
            <div class="row">
                <div class='col-sm-6 form-group'>
                    <div class="form-group col-6">
                        <label for="start_date"><strong>Start Date</strong></label>
                        <input type="date" required name="start_date" value="{{ date('Y-m-d') }}"
                            class="form-control" id="start_date">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class='col-sm-6 form-group'>
                    <div class="form-group col-6">
                        <label for="end_date"><strong>End Date</strong></label>
                        <input type="date" required name="end_date" value="{{ date('Y-m-d') }}"
                            class="form-control" id="end_date">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class='col-sm-12 form-group'>
                <label> Customers :</label>
                <select style="font-size: 12px; width:100%" id="customer_id" name="customer_id"
                    class="select2 mb-2 select2-multiple">
                    <option value=''> Choose </option>
                    @if ($customers)
                        @foreach ($customers as $item)
                            @php $selected = ''; @endphp
                            @if (isset($customerdirect) == $item->id)
                                @php $selected = 'selected'; @endphp
                            @endif
                            <option data-name="{{ $item->name }}" value='{{ $item->id }}' {{ $selected }}>
                                {{ $item->name }} </option>
                        @endforeach
                    @endif
                </select>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class='panel-footer'>
        <input type='submit' class='btn btn-success' value='Generate'/>
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

@endsection

**the code in controller**

```
 public function getStatement(Request $request)
{
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('customerslocations::customerstatementpdf');
    return $pdf->stream();
}
```

Comment: You need to use javascript to change the src of the embed or iframe

Comment: thank's @justrusty , i will try it.